# Pausing threads properly onPause() and onResume() with a SurfaceView and Thread in Android

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, onresume, onpause

To run the games that I've created on Android, I've been using a GamePanel contains the methods onDraw() and onTouch().  I also have been using a GameThread class that calls onDraw() and update() repeatedly.

My activity instantiates the GamePanel and my GamePanel instantiates the GameThread.

My onPause() just sets the condition in the while-loop inside the thread, run, to false.  My onResume() used to just set that equal to true, however that would give me a force close error (*see edit #1*) every time I tried to resume the app.

So instead to fix the problem I just re-instantiated the thread,

```
thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
```

This solved part of the problem, allowing me to minimize the app and then re-open it without a problem. However, when I was in the app and I locked my phone and then unlocked it (turning the screen on and off) the thread would never start. It would just be my game in a frozen state.

I know that my solution to the problem is extremely funky, and I would love to learn a more accepted and clean way to do this whole thing.

Here is the code (I left out a few lines that didn't seem relevant):

GameActivity:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gamePanel = new MainGamePanel(this);
    setContentView(gamePanel);

}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gamePanel.shutDown();

}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gamePanel.startUp();
}
```

GamePanel

```
public MainGamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);                  //adding the callback (this) to the surface  holder to intercept events
    thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);     // create the game loop thread
    setFocusable(true);                             // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
}
public void startUp() {
    thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
}

public void shutDown() {
    thread.setRunning(false);
}
```

GameThread

```
public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gameView) {
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gameView = gameView;
    this.run = true;
}
public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    this.run = run;
}
public void run() {
    Canvas c;//
    while (run) {
        c = null;
        try {
            c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {                  
                gameView.update();
                gameView.onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more information or how I can make my question more clear (also, did I present my code in an understandable manor?).

A little help will go a long way. Thanks in advance if you can give any suggestions.

**--EDIT #1--**

This was my log cat error when I got a force close.

```
12-23 14:01:34.288: E/AndroidRuntime(9484): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started.
```

**--EDIT #2--**

I tried what you said and changed my run() method to:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (true) {
        if (run) {/* run game thread */
            c = null;
            try {
                c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    gameView.update();
                    gameView.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It worked when I locked my phone, but when I minimized the app and reopened it I was presented with a black screen and after a few seconds a popup that said "MyApp isn't responding. Do you want to close it?".  I checked where it got up to and it seemed to get to the onPause() and the shutDown() but it never got to onResume();. Also, sometimes it even calls update() after it calls onPause() or shutDown(), which is weird.  (Got the info from LogCat)

Comment: What "force close" error did you get? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: Two observations: is the field run volatile? The thread might have never exited because the value of run was cached and when it changed it never read the new value; therefore it might still be running inside the while loop... Also, you should probably have in GameThread while(true){if(run){/*run game thread*/}else{try{Thread.sleep(sleepTime);}catch(Exception e){}}}

Comment: Your thread is already running and you are trying to start it, which means the thread never saw when the value of run changed from true to false. You need to change the field (variable) "run" in  GameThread to volatile (i.e., public volatile boolean run;)

Comment: I added volatile yesterday but unfortunately I still got the same errors.  Could it be sometime else?

Comment: Which errors? "IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started"? If so, don't do this: "thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);" since the thread is already running. Instead, have onResume/gamePanel.startUp() implement the following: "thread.setRunning(true);"